SlowCheetah: Transform with a default file
How can I transform a base file into a config file? I need to replicate a web.config transform step from .Net Standard:
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <TransformXml Source="Web._.config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="Web.config" />
</Target>

With this, I take a Web._.config file, apply a Config file and then output web.config
This keeps an original file and transforms into a new file.
How do you do this in .Net Core and/or with slowcheetah or is it possible? Alternative is to create a base file and in before build, copy over the base file then transform.

Do you mean you want transform a base file into a config file by slowcheetah  extension in VS? If so, did you check this document?
